# COUT gives strange number for simple C++ code

Tags: c++

I am trying to add a ASCII asterisk (*) frame around the hello world in a very simple C++ code.
It works but gives this strange number before the frame. Here is my sample code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Please enter your name" << endl;
  string name;
  cin >> name;

  string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
  string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
  string stars(greeting.size(), '*');

  cout << '**' << stars    <<'**' << endl;
  cout << '* ' << spaces   <<' *' << endl;
  cout << '* ' << greeting << ' *' << endl;
  cout << '**' << stars    <<'**' << endl;
  cout << '* ' << spaces   <<' *' << endl;
 
  return 0;

}
```

### Output

```
Please enter your name
tester
10794**************10794
10784              8234
10784Hello, tester!8234
10794**************10794
10784              8234
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why does it add these numbers before and after the string? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try double quote, so it looks like this:

```
cout << "**" << stars    <<"**" << endl;
```

:-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: oops. thank you. so silly.

Comment: OP:  FYI, using multiple letters inside single quotes, `'**'`, is consider a number and not a text string.  Text strings (multiple characters) are enclosed in **double** quotes, as in `"****"`.